# how to resolve the TCL script error when put it in crontab: "error writing "stdout": bad file number"?

Tags: cron, tcl, stdout, expect

I have a TCL script with function to write error log, but i meet the error as below when i put this script in crontab:

```
error writing "stdout": bad file number
    while executing
"puts $msg"
```

the code pieces are:

> if { $logLevel >= 0 } {
>
> ```
> puts $msg
>
> flush stdout
> ```
>
> }

but this script can run succeed manually, it only have error when i put it in crontab.

thanks, 
Emre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a program from cron, it runs with an unusual environment. In particular, there is no terminal, the environment variables are different, neither stdin nor stdout are normally available, and stderr is redirected so it gets emailed to you if anything fails. As we can see from the error message in your case, stdout is not open (technically, it only says its not open for writing, but even so); `puts` defaults to writing there if not told otherwise.

The basic fix? Don't write to stdout! Open a file somewhere else and write to that. Alternatively, define a redirection of stdout in your crontab entry so that it goes somewhere definite (and is thus available for writing to from inside your Tcl program).

Comment: Piping output to the [`logger`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?logger+1) utility might have sense for cron jobs, as the output goes to a well-known location.

Comment: I've never had a problem using stdout in cron jobs (mostly Solaris), frequently piping the output of a script in cron to mailx

Comment: @glenn: I had a look, and it seems to vary by which implementation of cron it is.

Comment: @Donal Fellows, so if i want to fix it, i should change crontab like below: `5 21 * * * myscript.sh > my.log 2>&1 `, right? thanks.

Comment: @DonalFellows, but looks it failed for the same reason. is there any workaround method to work if i don't want to change the script, because it works fine in normal shell environment. many thanks!

Comment: @EmreHe, try this: `5 21 * * * sh -c 'myscript.sh >mylog 2>&1'` -- that might provide the missing std* file descriptors