# Why is expect failing when the docker container is run without --interactive

Tags: docker, tcl, expect, stdio

I am getting an error when I run an expect script inside a docker container.

First I created a simple expect script `test.expect`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 

set timeout 3
#expect_before timeout { puts "\nTimeout fired"; exit 1 }

puts "--- Start"
lassign $argv name duration

spawn bash -c "echo Hello ${name} && sleep ${duration} "
expect {
    eof {
        puts "No timeout";
    }
}
puts "--- End"
```

Note: the `expect_before` is commented out at first

Now the docker image `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add bash expect

COPY test.expect /root
ENV PATH $PATH:/root

WORKDIR /root
ENTRYPOINT ["test.expect"]
```

Now build and run the docker:

```
$ docker build -t test-expect .
$ docker run -i test-expect Martin 2
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 2
Hello Martin
No timeout
--- End
$ docker run -i test-expect Martin 5
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 5
Hello Martin
--- End
$ docker run test-expect Martin 2
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 2
Hello Martin
No timeout
--- End
$ docker run test-expect Martin 5
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 5
Hello Martin
--- End
```

Both paths through the script work fine with or without docker `-i` (`--interactive`). Now I uncomment the `expect_before`. Rebuild and rerun:

```
$ docker build -t test-expect .
$ docker run -i test-expect Martin 2
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 2
Hello Martin
No timeout
--- End
$ docker run -i test-expect Martin 5
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 5
Hello Martin

Timeout fired
$ docker run test-expect Martin 2
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 2
error writing "stdout": bad file number
    while executing
"puts "--- End""
    (file "/root/test.expect" line 15)
$ docker run test-expect Martin 5
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 5
error writing "stdout": bad file number
    while executing
"puts "--- End""
    (file "/root/test.expect" line 15)
```

Naturally when I first saw this in my actual pipeline (GitHub workflows, calling Actions, running large containers, with convoluted scripts, that need my actual expect script) I assumed it was related to the fact that expect was being run in an environment where there was [no stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437703/how-to-resolve-the-tcl-script-error-when-put-it-in-crontab-error-writing-stdo) and or [stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280470/error-when-trying-to-use-puts-in-tcl-expect). It wasn't until I eventually created this much simpler test case did I find the actual cause of my error.

I cannot fathom why `expect_before` causes this behaviour, let alone what I can do to fix it.

Running `expect` with `-d` did not give me any insight

```
$ docker run test-expect Martin 5
expect version 5.45.4
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -df  argv[2] = /root/test.expect  argv[3] = Martin  argv[4] = 5
set argc 2
set argv0 "/root/test.expect"
set argv "Martin 5"
executing commands from command file /root/test.expect
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 5
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {7}
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp0"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
error writing "stdout": bad file number
    while executing
"puts "--- End""
    (file "/root/test.expect" line 15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon the [actual answer](http://www.wellho.net/forum/The-Tcl-programming-language/expect-expect-before-and-expect-after.html)!

> Rather than add all the alternatives into every *expect* command in your program, you can make use of *expect_before* and *expect_after*.  These allow you to set up alternative sequences that every subsequent *expect* command in the currently spawned process will react to in addition to the ones that you've explicitly written into the *expect* command.  Where the returned sequence from the spawned command matches several alternatives, the order of priority taken is
>
> ```
> expect_before
> expect
> expect_after
> ```
>
> Now - one word of caution.   **You should specify any *expect_before* and *expect_after* commands AFTER you have spawned the process you wish to control.**   Expect can control multiple spawned processes, and if you specify your *_before*s and *_after*s at the wrong point, you can end up applying them to the wrong process.
>
> If you have no spawned process at all and you *expect_before*, **you're liable to get erratic results - for example, an application which runs interactively but fails from *crontab***, or one which works on one release of an operating system but fails on the next release.   **Very hard problem to  identify if you're not aware of the risk!**

So the fix is really simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 

set timeout 3

puts "--- Start"
lassign $argv name duration

spawn bash -c "echo Hello ${name} && sleep ${duration} "
expect_before timeout { puts "\nTimeout fired"; exit 1 }
expect {
    eof {
        puts "No timeout";
    }
}
puts "--- End"
```

And now it always works regardless of the `-i` flag

```
$ docker run -i test-expect Martin 2
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 2
Hello Martin
No timeout
--- End
$ docker run -i test-expect Martin 5
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 5
Hello Martin

Timeout fired
$ docker run test-expect Martin 2
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 2
Hello Martin
No timeout
--- End
$ docker run test-expect Martin 5
--- Start
spawn bash -c echo Hello Martin && sleep 5
Hello Martin

Timeout fired
```

Comment: Nice piece of detective work.